# Jenkins and Ant not playing nicely with Jacoco

Tags: ant, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

When building the project with Ant directly I get a coverage report from Jacoco as expected, the .exec file is created and the corresponding reports directory is created in the test/reports directory. When building the project through Jenkins the jacoco.exec file is created but is empty and the actual reports directory is missing. 
I have tried various path configurations on the Jenkins side thus far without any luck, I am assuming this is some failure of interaction between Jenkins and Ant as the Jacoco plugin for Jenkins simply collects the coverage report output from the build and displays it.
I simply want to get a coverage reading on our Jenkins builds, has anyone been down this road? 
Thank you in advance for any and all assistance/advice.

**Edit**

Configures environment and runs XXXX tests.

```
<import file="build.xml" />
```

<..Properties and DIR values..../>

```
<!-- COMMMON ......................................................................................................-->
<target name="prepare-jdbc-for-tests">
<!...DB...Setup..ETC./>
</target>

<!-- JACOCO  .................................................................................................-->
<taskdef uri = "antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource = "org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
<classpath path = "${lib.test.dir}/jacocoant.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<target name  = "jacoco:report" if="${jacoco}">
    <jacoco:report>
        <!-- Collected execution data  ... -->
        <executiondata>
                <file file="${test.data.dir}/jacoco.exec" />
        </executiondata>
        <!--  class files and source files ... -->
        <structure name="XXXX Jacoco Coverage Report">
                <classfiles>
                        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
                </classfiles> 
                <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
                </sourcefiles>
        </structure>


        <!-- to produce reports in different formats. -->
        <html destdir="${test.reports.dir}/jacoco-report.html" />
        <csv destfile="${test.reports.dir}/report.csv" />
        <xml destfile="${test.reports.dir}/report.xml" />
     </jacoco:report>
</target>
```

<....COMPILE TASKS etc...../>

```
<!-- JUNIT .......................................................................................................-->
<target name="junit-report">
    <junitreport todir="${test.data.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${test.data.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${test.reports.dir}" />
    </junitreport>
</target>

<target name="junit-run-tests" depends="test-compile">
    <echo message="included test pattern = ${junit-run-tests.includes}" />
    <echo message="excluded test pattern = ${junit-run-tests.excludes}" />
    <property name="myclasspath" refid="test.runtime.classpath" />
    <echo message="classpath = ${myclasspath}" />

<jacoco:coverage destfile="${test.data.dir}/jacoco.exec" includes= "${junit-run-tests.includes}">
    <junit printsummary="false"
           haltonfailure="false"
           haltonerror="false"
           errorProperty="test.failed"
           failureProperty="test.failed"
           fork="true"
           forkMode="once"
           maxmemory="1024m"> 
        <classpath location="${build.instrumented.dir}" />
        <classpath location="${build.classes.dir}" />
        <!-- Ensures instrumented files are searched for first -->
        <classpath location="${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" />
        <classpath refid="test.runtime.classpath" />
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <formatter type="xml" />

        <batchtest todir="${test.data.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="${junit-run-tests.includes}"
                     excludes="${junit-run-tests.excludes}" />
        </batchtest>
        <sysproperty key="build.dir" value="${build.dir}" />

    </junit>
</jacoco:coverage>

    <antcall target="junit-report" />
    <antcall target="jacoco:report" />
    <antcall target="open-test-report" />

    <!--<fail message="Tests failed.  Check log and/or reports" if="test.failed"/>-->
</target>

<!--Integration TEST Task Definitions---/>
...
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be helpful to include your code.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor an excellent point, forgive me apparently having a dull moment. Edited to include build file.

Comment: This has been solved, you must be careful with the 'includes' and excludes' clauses within the Jacoco target, if the syntax isn't quite right it will include nothing and subsequently show 0% coverage across all classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been solved, you must be careful with the 'includes' and excludes' clauses within the Jacoco target, if the syntax isn't quite right it will include nothing and subsequently show 0% coverage across all classes.

Comment: Your answer is frustrating - *how* must one be careful with the 'includes' and excludes' clauses? *what* counts as not-quite-right syntax? Where is the documentation?